# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set' returning multiple param vals

Tags: python-3.x

I'm kinda beginner using python from javascript, and wanting to return param vals together into an api... I've been trying to use + though it give's me error

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'"

How do correcting this?

```js
def generate_ad(product_type: str, product_name: str, platform: str, audience: str) -> str:
    # Load your API key from an environment variable or secret management service
    product_type = f'Write a creative ad for {product_type} '
    product_name = f'named {product_name}'
    platform = f'to run on {platform} '
    audience = f'aimed at {audience}:'
    
    enriched_prompt = product_type + product_name + platform + audience
```

test API call:

```js
from fastapi import FastAPI
from riplir import generate_ad


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/generate_snippet")
async def creative_ad_api(product_type: str, product_name: str , platform: str, audience: str):
    snippet = generate_ad({product_type} + {product_name} + {platform} + {audience})
    
    return {
        "message": snippet,
        }

# uvicorn riplir_api:app --reload
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing to this function? If they are strings, it should work as expected.

Comment: @lnogueir I have updated the post to include the test file I have that has the test API call

Comment: In python, you call a function by separating the arguments with commas like `generate_ad(product_type, product_name, platform, audience)`. The way your code is doing it now is passing in a single argument. The braces around each variable creates a set with that single item, and the + tries to add them together, which isn't supported for sets.

Comment: @rchome ah! I cant believe I missed that lol thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `generate_ad` function input is a string, which you can build using f-string:

```
@app.get("/generate_snippet")
async def creative_ad_api(product_type: str,
                          product_name: str,
                          platform: str,
                          audience: str):
    snippet = generate_ad(f'{product_type} + {product_name} + {platform} + {audience}')

    return {
    "message": snippet,
    }
```

Or the input is a set, which can be built from the 4 string parameters:

```
@app.get("/generate_snippet")
async def creative_ad_api(product_type: str,
                          product_name: str,
                          platform: str,
                          audience: str):
    snippet = generate_ad(set(product_type, product_name, platform, audience))

    return {
    "message": snippet,
    }
```

Or simply, you have 4 inputs:

```
@app.get("/generate_snippet")
async def creative_ad_api(product_type: str,
                          product_name: str,
                          platform: str,
                          audience: str):
    snippet = generate_ad(product_type, product_name, platform, audience)

    return {
    "message": snippet,
    }
```